# mark text in g transform css to pulsate

Tags: html, css, svg, tspan

I got a template in SVG data.
Here I have a text I would like to pulsate.

Html:

```
<tspan class="text animated pulse" x="14.325" y="39.18">50</tspan></text>
```

it´s doesn't work.

Here is a link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyemZz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try it like this ?

```
tspan.text.animated.pulse {
  animation: pulse-text infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes pulse-text {
  0% {font-size: 1em;}
  50% {font-size: 1.1em;}
  100% {font-size: 1em;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hy, thanks for anwser.. no this not option ;((
i muss speek this css class *text animated pulse*

```
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,165.514,113.873)" class="no-kerning">
<text stroke-width="0" stroke="#5F5E5E" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#5F5E5E" font-family="CurrencyRegular" font-size="40"><tspan class="text animated pulse" x="14.325" y="39.18">50</tspan></text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

For tspan element transform property will not work. You can try animating font-size.
Check the updated code.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKVOzB

code changes:-

```
tspan.text.animated.pulse {
  animation: pulse 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
   0%,100% {font-size:40px;}
   50% {font-size:50px;}
}
```